# is a php password reset function like this secure?

Tags: php, security

I have a area on my pages protectet by a script like this: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
What I need now is some kind of password reset function in case of forgotten password.
There are just a few users and I try to make it as easy as possible.

So how I think it will work:

1. the user enters there e-mail adress
2. the user receives an e-mail with a link containing the sha512-hashed password and it's username as GET parameter
3. The script checks wether the username and password hash fits
4. the user can now enter there new password

Are there any strong security weaknesses doing it like this or is it a common way? What's best practice for that? I really don't want any additional security questions or such stuff...

Update: The passwords are hashed and salted.

Comment: sha512 hashes things, it doesn't encrypt them

Comment: Also, you need to make `Absolutely` sure that you only send email to their address which was `already` registered with you. You cannot allow them to enter any email address and a username to get the password. Anybody could then come in, enter a known username and get away with it

Comment: you'r right Quentin, I changed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how a tentative flow should be:

1. User clicks on "Password Reset" Link.
2. Email is dispatched to the address user registered with.
3. Email contains a unique link that expires in 1 hour.
4. User clicks link and is taken to page with password field.
5. User enters new password, password is hashed and saved.

Just FYI, you should never transmit passwords or their hashes in any way.

1. Passwords should never be saved in raw form or as unsalted hashes.
2. Hashes should never be transmitted.

Comment: ah forgot to write that the passwords are stored as salted hashes. What do you think abouth sending e.g. just the first 15 letters of the hash?

Comment: That won't work either, just use uniqid() to generate a unique string and send that.

Answer (score 10):

That isn't as safe as it should be.

You are sending the username and password (admittedly in a form that is hard to reverse engineer) over email (which is not secure) — and those usernames and passwords might be reused on other sites.

Use a randomly generated string of characters, not any real credentials. Store the random string in a database and use it to look up which user to reset the password for. Only allow the string to work for a limited time.

Answer (score 1):

The only place an encrypted password hash should be is in your server backend and nowhere else.

An attacker can brute-force the hash using nearly limitless processing ability if he has the hash to check against, while in any other case they will have to be limited by your server's capacity and you will be immediately aware.

If you want to keep it secure, generate random password reset keys and send them to the user's registration email (and none other - email security is the user's problem). If the user returns to the site with that key (as GET parameter usually), then you can let the user access a password change form.

As far as I know, this is one of the most common and secure methods of password resets today  (2factor auth and the like notwithstanding).